# How to allow the "CellFeed" of Google Spreadsheet to return the blank cells as well (using Java)?

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

Previously, I was using the ListFeed to access the Google Spreadsheet and fetch the rows. As the number of rows increased I needed to shift to the CellFeed in order to fetch the data in batches.

I am facing problems when using Cell Feeds that the null or empty values in the Google Spreadsheet are not returned. Whereas when I was using ListFeed it used to return the blank values as well.

Following is the piece of code:

```
        URL cellFeedUrl2 = new URI(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL.toString() + "?min-row=2&max-row=5").toURL();  
        CellFeed cellFeed2 = service.getFeed(cellFeedUrl2, CellFeed.class);
        for (CellEntry cell : cellFeed2.getEntries()){  
            System.out.println(cell.getCell().getValue() + "\t");  
        }
```

Actual Output:
1. Row 1
*Name

Email

DOB

Phone*
2. Row 2
*Name

Email

Phone*

(No DOB because it is empty in the spreadsheet but still it should appear)
Expected Output:
1. Row 1
*Name

Email

DOB

Phone*

2.Row 2
*Name

Email

DOB

Phone*

Please suggest!

Comment: Did you already check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/data#work_with_cell-based_feeds) of Google for Cell-based Feeds?

Comment: Thanks @KENdi, Yes, I had gone through the documentation of Google Cell-based Feeds. I met with the solution. Posting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add an extra parameter to the URL as follows:

```
URL cellFeedUrl2 = new URI(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL.toString() + "?return-empty=true&min-row=2&max-row=5").toURL();  
    CellFeed cellFeed2 = service.getFeed(cellFeedUrl2, CellFeed.class);
    for (CellEntry cell : cellFeed2.getEntries()){  
        System.out.println(cell.getCell().getValue() + "\t");  
    }
```

The parameter "return-empty=true" returns the blank values as null and thereby can be handled using try-catch block if exceptions occur.